# Looking for official download link of Windows version of DOS game "Crime Fighter"

Tags: dos, crime-fighter

I am looking for the official download page for the game [crime fighter](https://www.myabandonware.com/game/crime-fighter-2ch). It was a top down action strategy type of game

This game was shareware initially but made freeware later on. Sometime ago (a long while ago) I was able to download a windows compatible version of this game from the authors website. Now I can't seem to find the author's website or a link to the Windows version (I probably ran it in XP or Windows 7, I don't even know if it will work in Windows 10). Most Google searches bring up DOS version download links from abandonware websites.

Is a link to the author's original website available? Or a link to a reliable backup? The original  game was German (but had a language selection option inside) so I might not have been searching for the correct Google terms.

Comment: You said you found a dos version right? Does that work in something like DOSBox?

Comment: @TimmyJim I haven't checked it recently but last time when I did I think I remember it was working. There's also some visual enhancements in the Windows version, and when the DOS version is played in DOSBox, one section of the game (safe cracking) is almost unplayable.

Comment: I may have found https://www.old-games.com/download/5175/crime-fighter, but try it at your own risk. I don't think though that this question is really on topic though.

Comment: Just for anyone interested, the link above is paywalled. This particular game was released for free by the author.

Answer (score 2):

After some digging around I found the author's site: https://www.pssoft.de/english/index.html

Different versions of the game can be downloaded for free from the download page: https://www.pssoft.de/english/download.html